# Fastest way to clear cobblestone blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, I am a bit of an expansionist and sometimes I like to 'reclaim' land from large bodies of water. I built a wall from the bottom of the water area to the surface as a retainer wall to keep the rest of the water coming back, and filled the inside in using lava buckets... Here's my problem: is there a faster way to remove the stone/cobblestone blocks from the lava without using TNT, because if I damage the retainer wall my work will be completely undone when the surrounding ocean floods it again.

Comment: Why don't you use sponges to clear the water? much easier...

Comment: ....... YOU CAN DO THAT!? I didn't know you could do that but I've already used the fill command to do it thanks for next time though.

Answer (score 1):

TNT can be used to safely clear solid chunks of stone and cobblestone. TNT will destroy a 5x5x5 solid block of stone or cobblestone if placed in the middle of the block. As long as you keep the TNT at least 4 blocks from the walls and you don't have any air holes, you'll be fine.

Alternatively, if you aren't adverse to using console commands, the `fill` command can be used to replace all blocks in a given region with another block.

Comment: I actually use commands to swap back and forth between survival and creative so commands don't bother me thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Mego mentions about TNT, you can also [Enchant](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Enchantments) a pickaxe with **Efficiency** to increase it's mining speed. Depending on the level of efficiency, your mining will get faster and faster. here's an overview of how each level of Efficiency affects your speed:

- No Efficiency: 100% (normal mining speed)
- Level I = 130%
- Level II = 169%
- Level III = 220%
- Level IV = 286%
- Level V = 371%

For the fastest results, a Gold Pickaxe would be your best bet, but it doesn't have a lot of durability, you'd have to also enchant it with Unbreaking to get a pick that would work for longer periods of time. Your best bet would be to enchant a Diamond Pickaxe instead: this will give you the durability you want RE: removing large chunks of cobble, while also being relatively fast in doing so.

Comment: As I said above I use creative mode for things of this nature. Could you imagine all the lava buckets I'd need if I didn't? I'd spend more time looking for lava than doing the job. So a faster pickaxe would not help here. My problem comes from the sheer size of the area and not the speed I'm clearing it.

Comment: @KeeperofTime - Fair enough, sorry I couldn't help :). I just saw the title 'Fastest way to clear cobblestone blocks' and it isn't specified in the question body if you meant survival or creative, so I didn't know at the time of writing.

Comment: It's no problem I was a bit rushed in my explanation anyway. My wrist was hurting from so much clicking lol.